# How can I insert Null value in the entity (EJB3)?

Tags: ejb, entity, ejb-3.0, entity-relationship, ejb-3.1

I'm working on EJB3. I want to insert Null value in the table.

Eg. I'm having a table called "Students" which has columns fields such as

```
String name;
String class;
Set<Subjects> subjects;
```

subjects field have the JoinTable "student_subjects" with fields `joinColumns` "student_name" of "Students" table and `inverseJoinColumns` "subjects_name" of "subjects" table

What I want is when I add a new student there will be a entry in "Students" table.

Also in the "student_subjects" table. but values must be student_name (not null) and NULL for "subjects_name". Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [nullable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#nullable%28%29) attribute of the [@Column](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) JPA annotation.

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private String studentName;

@Column(nullable = true)
private String subjectsName;
```